# Angular JS viewContentLoaded loading twice on initial homepage load

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I noticed that on my initial homepage load, my viewContentLoaded is firing twice, why is that ?

```
app.run(function 
    ($rootScope,$log) {
      'use strict';
      $rootScope.$state = $state;
      $log.warn("gets here");

      $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded',function(){
        $log.warn("gets here2");
      });
    });
```

Output on page load

```
"gets here" 
"gets here2" 
"gets here2"
```

And my routing as follows

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('', '/');

  // For any unmatched url, send to 404
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/404');

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'views/search.html',
      controller: 'SearchCtrl'
    })
```

My Index.html

```
  <div id="canvas">
    <ng-include src="'views/partials/header.html'"></ng-include>
    <!-- container -->
    <div ui-view ></div>
    <!-- /container -->
    <ng-include src="'views/partials/footer.html'"></ng-include>
  </div>
```

Comment: How many ui-view do you have ?

Comment: Just one, added above

Comment: How many XHR Requests do you have in your console?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is just specifics of uiView directive implementation. It fires the **$viewContentLoaded** event during initialization (link) phase. At this point no state is yet known, but the event is still fired.

And then after the event is fired again once the **$state** service actually resolves your **home** state, makes transition into it, loads templates etc.

So to sum up, it happens not because of bad configuration nor your templates are loaded twice. It's just how **uiView** works.

You can even verify it by completely commenting out your state definitions and most of your index.html contents (except for **ui-view** itself). The **$viewContentLoaded** will still be fired once.

Source code excerpts:

**uiView** directive declaration:

```
{
    restrict: 'ECA',
    terminal: true,
    priority: 400,
    transclude: 'element',
    compile: function (tElement, tAttrs, $transclude) {
      return function (scope, $element, attrs) {
        ...
        updateView(true);
        ...
      }
    }
 }
```

and the **updateView** function

```
    function updateView(firstTime) {
      ...
      currentScope.$emit('$viewContentLoaded');
      currentScope.$eval(onloadExp);
    }
```

For more information see complete source code on **GitHub** - [viewDirective.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/db68914cd6c821e7dec8155bd33142a3a97f5453/src/viewDirective.js)

Answer (score 5):

### Why it is getting call twice?

I'm sure that your `serach.html` page has again contain a `ui-view`, that is calling trying to load a view and at the end `$emiting` the `$viewContentLoaded` event. Simply As many number of `ui-view` rendered on the html that will surely `$emit` the `$viewContentLoaded` event.

---

As you want to make sure your event should be get call only once then you should put event on $stateChangeSuccess which will ensure that it will get fired only once after all the ui-views gets loaded via state.

**Code**

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
   ///...code here 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be happen when **SearchCtrl** will be called twice.

e.g.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'views/search.html',
      controller: 'SearchCtrl'
    })
```

and in **index.html**

```
<body ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
    <div id="canvas">
    <ng-include src="'views/partials/header.html'"></ng-include>
    <!-- container -->
    <div ui-view ></div>
    <!-- /container -->
    <ng-include src="'views/partials/footer.html'"></ng-include>
  </div>
</body>
```